# None of the tests of pallet-template is running

Tags: testing

When I run `cargo test`, it shows in console that:

```
running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s
```

for `node-template`, `pallet-template` and `node-template` runtime.

Here is the code in file `pallets/template/mock.rs`

```
use crate as pallet_template;
use frame_support::traits::{ConstU16, ConstU64};
use sp_core::H256;
use sp_runtime::{
    traits::{BlakeTwo256, IdentityLookup},
    BuildStorage,
};

type Block = frame_system::mocking::MockBlock<Test>;
type UncheckedExtrinsic = frame_system::mocking::MockUncheckedExtrinsic<Test>;
pub(crate) const ACCOUNT_A:u64 = 0;
pub(crate) const ACCOUNT_B:u64 = 1;

// Configure a mock runtime to test the pallet.
frame_support::construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Test where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic
    {
        System: frame_system::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>},
        TemplateModule: pallet_template::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>},
        ElectionProviderMultiPhase: pallet_election_provider_multi_phase,
        Staking: pallet_staking,
        Session: pallet_session,
        Assets: pallet_assets,
        VoterList: pallet_bags_list::<Instance1>,
        Historical: pallet_session::historical::{Pallet},
        
        
    }
);

impl frame_system::Config for Test {
    type BaseCallFilter = frame_support::traits::Everything;
    type BlockWeights = ();
    type BlockLength = ();
    type DbWeight = ();
    type RuntimeOrigin = RuntimeOrigin;
    type RuntimeCall = RuntimeCall;
    type Nonce = u64;
    type Hash = H256;
    type Hashing = BlakeTwo256;
    type AccountId = u64;
    type Lookup = IdentityLookup<Self::AccountId>;
    type Block = Block;
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type BlockHashCount = ConstU64<250>;
    type Version = ();
    type PalletInfo = PalletInfo;
    type AccountData = ();
    type OnNewAccount = ();
    type OnKilledAccount = ();
    type SystemWeightInfo = ();
    type SS58Prefix = ConstU16<42>;
    type OnSetCode = ();
    type MaxConsumers = frame_support::traits::ConstU32<16>;
}

impl pallet_template::Config for Test {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type WeightInfo = ();
    type Token = Balances; // <Self as pallet_balances::Config>::Currency;
    type Score = Assets;
    type TaskCredit = Assets;
    // type ScoreNow = ScoreType;
    type ScoreBalance = AssetBalance;
    type TaskCreditBalance = AssetBalance;
    // type TaskCredit = Balances;
    type TokenToTaskCredit = Identity;
    type MaxTasksOwned = ConstU32<100>;
    type AssetToCurrencyBalance = Identity;
    type CurrencyToAssetBalance = Identity;
}

// Build genesis storage according to the mock runtime.
pub fn new_test_ext() -> sp_io::TestExternalities {
    frame_system::GenesisConfig::<Test>::default().build_storage().unwrap().into()
}
```

And in `pallets/template/tests.rs`

```
use super::*;
use crate::{mock::*, Error, Event};
use frame_support::{assert_noop, assert_ok};

#[test]
fn it_works_for_default_value() {
    new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
        // Go past genesis block so events get deposited
        System::set_block_number(1);
        // Dispatch a signed extrinsic.
        assert_ok!(TemplateModule::do_something(RuntimeOrigin::signed(1), 42));
        // Read pallet storage and assert an expected result.
        assert_eq!(TemplateModule::something(), Some(42));
        // Assert that the correct event was deposited
        System::assert_last_event(Event::SomethingStored { something: 42, who: 1 }.into());
    });
}

#[test]
fn correct_error_for_none_value() {
    new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
        // Ensure the expected error is thrown when no value is present.
        assert_noop!(
            TemplateModule::cause_error(RuntimeOrigin::signed(1)),
            Error::<Test>::NoneValue
        );
    });
}

#[test]
fn the_task_is_stored_correctly() {
    new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
        // Ensure the expected error is thrown when no value is present.
        assert_ok!(TemplateModule::deposit_token_to_taskcredit(RuntimeOrigin::signed(ACCOUNT_A), 1234));
        assert_ok!(TemplateModule::create_task(RuntimeOrigin::signed(ACCOUNT_A), "hello", 12));
        
    });
}
```

But it still runs the tests written in `runtime/src.rs`.
I also tried:
`cargo test -p pallet-template`
or cd to folder `pallets/template` then run `cargo test`, but nothing works.

How to solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: I found the problem, I need to add ```pub mod mock;
mod tests;``` in the ```lib.rs``` file. I made it be comment before.

Comment: That would be it. It's a pity IDEs don't warn about files not being included. Actually I think the intellij rust plugin probably does warn you about this.

Comment: @Squirrel i use VS code. :( Rust-analyzer sometimes just makes me more confused.

Answer (score 2):

Testing the runtime crate won't cover the pallet crates.

To test a single pallet

```
cargo test -p pallet-template
```

To test the whole workspace

```
# run this under the project root
cargo test
```

Comment: actually I tried this but it was still the same. running 0 tests